# Fetch object that have existing many-2-many related objects in django

Tags: django, django-models

Posts may be assigned to one or more categories, and categories may contain multiple posts.

Here are my models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=31)


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    content = models.TextField()
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

I don't know how to fetch all categories that have at least one post assigned to them without query all of them and checking in loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `isnull` lookup with reverse manager:

```
Category.objects.filter(post__isnull=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following query will do the trick:

```
Category.objects.filter(post__isnull=False).distinct()
```

The filter will perform a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (it is possible that since `__isnull` should be `False`, this is optimized to a simple `JOIN`) on the `post_category` table, and thus all rows of this `JOIN` where the `post_id` is not `NULL` will be retained.

The `.distinct()` is necessary (well not strictly necessary of course) to avoid returning the *same* `Category` multiple times if that category has multiple related `Post`s. The query will `JOIN` on the `post_category` table, and thus act like a *multiplier*, by using `.distinct()`, we can avoid that.

The *opposite*: categories *without* a `Post` does not need this `.distinct()`, since the `NULL` row only occurs once when there are no realted posts:

```
#  Opposite query, no distict() necessary

Category.objects.filter(post=None)
```